# Overriding store.js with key from locale.json

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, vuex, vue-router, vue-i18n

I need to dynamically pass the data from current locale to an array in store.js.
the array looks like this:

```
skills: [
      {
        id: "1",
        type: "hard",
        title: "Technical Skills",
        mastery: "low",
      },
        ]
});
```

And so I need to  replace this  `title: "Technical skills",` with the data from locale json file.

So if I do like this:
`store.js:`

```
import en from "../src/locales/en.json";
import fr from "../src/locales/fr.json";
import it from "../src/locales/it.json";
skills: [
      {
        id: "1",
        type: "hard",
        title: `${en.hardSkills.TechnicalSkills}`,
        mastery: "low",
      },
export { store };
```

It does kinda work. And if I change `en` with `fr` or `it` it will change the displayed language. But of course I need to change languages from the website and not from the code.

Perhaps it has to be something like this:

```
title: `${$i18n.locale.hardSkills.TechnicalSkills}`,
```

But in this case `$i18n` is not defined.

I can't figure it out

the object in `locales/fr.json`

```
"hardSkills" : {
  "TechnicalSkills" : "Compétences techniques"
}
```

and `locales/it.json`

```
"hardSkills" : {
  "TechnicalSkills" : "Abilità tecniche"
}
```

and of course `locales/en.json`

```
"hardSkills" : {
  "TechnicalSkills" : "Technical skills"
}
```

Comment: {{ $t(hardSkill.title) }} without quote should work, if "Marketing skills" is a key and its value is the translation you want to display. It would be better, if you share your translation files too.

Comment: Expanding upon the above comment - The value passed to `$t()` must be a string separated by `.` that represents the index of the text within the JSON object that you want to display. If it is not, it will not work with this approach.

Comment: Yes I know how to place translated item inside of a div.
But I am looking for another thing.
I am cycling through an array of skills. Each skill has 4 keys: id, type, title and mastery.
The array is filtered so soft skills are displayed in one vue-component and hard skills in another. There's also 5 different styles according to the level of mastery.
And what I need is to access the 'title' of the skill and replace is with a translated one.

Comment: I tried to place it like that:
``title: `${t.hardSkills.TechnicalSkills}`,``
 but I got an error `src/store/store.js
  55:19  error  't' is not defined  no-undef`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright it's done. Here's the solution.

`store.js:`

```
skills: [
     {
       id: "1",
       type: "hard",    
     },
     {
       id: "2",
       type: "hard",        
     },
```

`fr.json`: //just keep the structure, it's the same for any other language.

```
 "hardSkills": {
    "Technical skills":  "Compétences techniques",
    "Computer skills": "Compétences informatiques",
}
```

`*.vue`

```
   <v-col
              v-for="hardSkill in hardSkills"
              :key="hardSkill.id"
              cols="auto"
              
            >
              {{ $t(`hardSkills.${hardSkill.title}`) }}
            
   </v-col>
```